# Load random sound clip

Tags: php, javascript, html, random

Trying to use php to load a random sound clip on page load/refresh. For some reason I get this error:

> Warning:
>   dir(http://daveywhitney.com/randomizer/clips/)
>   [function.dir]: failed to open dir:
>   not implemented in
>   /home/cheapra1/public_html/daveywhitney.com/randomizer/index.php
>   on line 19
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   read() on a non-object in
>   /home/cheapra1/public_html/daveywhitney.com/randomizer/index.php
>   on line 20

When using this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>RANDOMIZER</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>RANDOM SOUND GENERATOR</h1>

<br />

<?php 

$i=0;
$myDirectory = dir("http://daveywhitney.com/randomizer/clips/");
while($file=$myDirectory->read())
{
$array[$i]=$file;
$i++;
}
$myDirecotry->close();

$num = count($array);
$random = rand(0, $num);

include "$array[$random]";



?>



</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you try to open remote dir via dir function, you cant do it, see in this link http://php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php the GUILLE@GARGANO function to remote dir

Comment: yes this site is on my server

Comment: @Haim completely off topic, there is a complaint about an edit approval of yours:  [Reporting person who automatically approve suggested edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95674) you may want to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any self-respecting web server, when seeing this:

dir("http://daveywhitney.com/randomizer/clips/");

will get very angry. It looks like your server is self respecting! Yay! But what does that mean for you and **how do you fix it?**

The problem is that `"http://daveywhitney.com/randomizer/clips/"` is actually an HTTP request String. This means that only things which can go to HTTP requests can try to read from it -- unfortunately, `dir` is not that type of function.

**So, that's the problem, how do you fix it?**

You actually have a couple of options.

First, if the directory exists on your server, you could simply look up the directory manually yourself. Simply replace `"http://daveywhitney.com/` with something on your local path (maybe `/var/www/htdocs/randomizer`?)

If it isn't a local directory, that does not mean you are SOL. Apache, for one, will output the contents of a directory in valid HTML, which means it can be parsed with `DOMDocument`.

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://daveywhitney.com/randomizer/clips/');
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$doc->getElementsByTagName('a'); //?? Not sure if that is right fn name.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could this be the local path? /public_html/daveywhitney.com/randomizer/clips

Comment: It could also be the path in your homedir, so you'd actually want `/home/*username*/public_html/davey....`

Comment: @Nanne & @Davey OH! Yes! It probably won't be in `/public_html/...`. That first `/` means "Look at the root of the file system", and while it *could* be there, that is very doubtful.